# How to choose value from an option list using PyQt4.QtWebKit

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, qtwebkit

I'm trying to auto-select a birthday from an option list on my website by using PyQt4.QtWebKit, but I'm having trouble doing this.

When I want to select a radio button I do this:

```
doc = webview.page().mainFrame().documentElement()
g = doc.findFirst("input[id=gender]")
g.setAttribute("checked", "true")
```

Or set some text input:

```
doc = webview.page().mainFrame().documentElement()
s = doc.findFirst("input[id=say_something]")
s.setAttribute("value", "Say Hello To My Little Friends")
```

But how do I select a month from this option list?

```html
<select tabindex="11" name="birthday_m">
    <option value="">---</option>
    <option value="1">JAN</option>
    <option value="2">FEB</option>
    <option value="3">MAR</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `QWebKit` classes use [CSS2 selector syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching) to find elements.

So the required option could be found like this:

```
doc = webview.page().mainFrame().documentElement()
option = doc.findFirst('select[name="birthday_m"] > option[value="3"]')
```

and then the `selected` attribute can be set on the option element like this:

```
option.setAttribute('selected', 'true')
```

However, for some reason, this does not immediately update the page (and nor does calling `webview.reload()`).

So if you need an immediate update, a better way might be to get the `select` element:

```
doc = webview.page().mainFrame().documentElement()
select = doc.findFirst('select[name="birthday_m"]')
```

and then set the selected option like so:

```
select.evaluateJavaScript('this.selectedIndex = 3')
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way :

```
doc.evaluateJavaScript('document.getElementsByName("birthdate_m")[0].options[3].selected = true')
```

If you have any suggestions, on how to improve it, please let me knnow.