# Selecting a value from an option list using pyqt4.QtWebKit.QWebPage

Tags: javascript, python, html, pyqt4, qtwebkit

First a little background info:

I'm a little new to data scraping, I started earlier this week. I've been trying to scrape data from 2 websites, I noticed that the information I wanted was dynamically loaded with java scripts (I think), so a simple attempt at downloading the webpage HTML with the python urllib2 package, didn't give the information wanted. I did lots of research and settled on using the PyQT4 package to download the fully loaded HTMLs (with the information loaded from the java scripts), I chose PyQT4 because I couldn't get other packages (eg. selerium) to work. The information that I want that is in these websites is stored in HTML tables, and they show up as fancy tables when you actually load the page in a browser.

Now onto the main question:

Using PyQT4 I managed to download full HTMLs, but I noticed that the webpages that I downloaded didn't actually have the full table of information I was looking for because both websites paginated the tables of information, but they gave an option to show various numbers of rows of the tables in a dropdown list, including the option to show all. So I looked for a way to select a value from the dropdown list through PyQT4, I found this link:

[How to choose value from an option list using PyQt4.QtWebKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542312/how-to-choose-value-from-an-option-list-using-pyqt4-qtwebkit).

I tried everything the answers on that page suggested but nothing seemed to work, I also tried what is suggested here:

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/52161-How-to-choose-value-from-(html)-option-list-using-WebKit

But it also didnt work.
The HTML code of the dropdown lists from both websites are below:

1:

```
<div class="dataTables_length" id="datatable-1_length">
  <label> Show
     <select aria-controls="datatable-1" class="form-control input-sm" name="datatable-1_length">
        <option value="10">
           10
        </option>
        <option value="25">
           25
        </option>
        <option value="50">
           50
        </option>
        <option value="100">
           100
        </option>
        <option value="-1">
           All
        </option>
      </select>
      entries
    </label>
 </div>
```

2:

```
 <div class="dataTables_length" id="qs-rankings_length">
    <label>
       <span class="result-mune">
          <span>
             Results
          </span>
          per page:
       </span>
       <select aria-controls="qs-rankings" class="" name="qs-rankings_length">
          <option value="100">
             100
          </option>
          <option value="200">
             200
          </option>
          <option value="-1">
             All
          </option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Is there a way to download the full tables from the websites?

Thanks